# cocos2d v3 chipmunk collision method not firing

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, detection, chipmunk

ok so i've been messing around with chipmunk a bit, and i can get two sprites to bounce off of each other, but when i try to use the following method, it never fires,

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair tower:(CCNode *)nodeA BG:    
   (CCNode *)nodeB
   {
   NSLog(@"HELLO");
   return YES;
   }
```

Heres where I create the physics node:

```
    _physics = [CCPhysicsNode node];
    _physics.debugDraw = YES;
    [self addChild:_physics z:1];
    _physics.collisionDelegate = self;
```

I use this code to create the first sprite:

```
    background = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:gameLevelImage];
    [background setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2)];
    background.physicsBody.collisionType = @"BG";
    background.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:50 andCenter:self.position];
```

and this for the other :

```
    tower = [[TowerType alloc] initWithTheGame:self location:ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2)];
    [towers addObject:tower];
    [self MenuItemsVisible];
    tower.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:50 andCenter:tower.position];
    tower.physicsBody.collisionType = @"tower";
```

I also have the  protocol in the h file.

if anyone knows whats happening help would be greatly appreciated. (:

Comment: Any chance you got it to work? I am suffering from the same problem. It seems like the collisionType is just not setting for some reason.

Comment: No, still haven't, can't find an answer anywhere ):

Comment: I would say just make sure your sprites are allocated properly before you try to set the collisionType. That was the issue for me.

Comment: Wow that was it for me too. thanks so much (:

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer below. Accept that so its easier for others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are both bodies under the same CCPhysicsNode?

Second, ccPhysicsCollisionBegin is just called when the collision BEGIN, so as both of your bodies are one over the other and they aparenttly will move together due to gravity the collision will never begin, because they started colliding. The cycle for collision evaluation is:

ccPhysicsCollisionBegin: called once both bodies start colliding
ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve: called every frame update, before physics calculations
ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve : called every frame, after physics calculations
ccPhysicsCollisionSeparates: called once they separate

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sprites are allocated properly before you try to set the collisionType. That was the issue for me in my similar case.